# Struts 2 - struts tags error

Tags: struts2

[image]
I had this message when trying to execute struts 2 application. Please anyone can help? Should i provide additional info?

Comment: Please post text for text; a screen shot may not be viewable or meaningful. Copy-and-paste instead. Also, Umesh's answer is correct, and you neither upvoted nor accepted it; IMO you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a filter in your web.xml for struts. Something like this

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though i am not able to see the image clearly and what the error is there, but looking in to the URL you are hitting i can tell you the cause of this exception.

In Struts2 you need to call the filter for every request in order to make Struts2 specific tag works ,since calling filter means letting framework to do its init work so that it should make available you things needed by you, in your case you are hitting a jsp page directly which means you are not letting S2 filter and its other associated classes to do the initial work and due to this Struuts2 tags do not have the required data which is cause of this error.

i suggest you to use action to make call for other JSP so as to let framework do its work

Comment: But how about to prevent those error and redirect user to a well explain error message, how to do this?

Comment: @OSIFY: that error message was due to the wrong way of using framework, but if you want to show any other messages you can configure global exception handler in Struts2